# How do I select the best curve that describes my data?

Tags: python, scipy, regression, curve-fitting

I have the following problem: I have the data below, in black, and the three curves that try to describe this data. I don't know their analytical expression. However, is there any method I can use to identify which one best describes my data? What I have are the sets of points (x,y) for each one of curves. Could I use this information?

Does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

[image]

Comment: Strange : How the three curves are drawn if their analytical expression are not known ?

Answer (score 1):

Without any clue about the equation model one can find many approximate equations. For example :

[image]

Note : The data used and the points drawn on this figure come from scanning the pixels of the graph joint to the question. This is not accurate.